# SQL case statements to change values

Tags: sql, plsql, unpivot

This is my code to do part of what I want to do:

```
SELECT uID, ColumnName, ColumnResult
FROM table
UNPIVOT
(
ColumnResult
for ColumnName in (COL1,COL2,COL3)
 )u
```

This returns something like this:

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query which replaces the column name with the new value:

```
select uID,
  case ColumnName 
    when 'COL1' then 'columnOne'
    when 'COL2' then 'columnTwo'
    when 'COL3' then 'columnThree'
  end ColumnName, 
  ColumnResult
from TABLE
unpivot
(
  ColumnResult
  for ColumnName in (COL1,COL2,COL3)
)u;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/20163/4)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the case that might extend better:

```
'column'||regexp_replace(to_char(to_date(substr(ColumnName,4),'J'),'Jsp'),'[ -]','') ColumnName,
```

This works into the hundreds.